# Ubuntu and HTPC related questions?

Tags: 14.10, resolution, fonts, tv

I just built myself a 5th gen Intel nuc system to run Ubuntu(14.10) and Kodi. Right now the problem is I will be sitting at about 12 feet away from my tv screen, which is a recent-ish 32in 1080p Sony TV. The problem is from that distance I can't read anything at all. I scaled it up 2x, but that messed a few things up, so I had to move scaling down to 1.8x(or what ever is after 1.75x) scaling. I also increased font size to large. Problem is that many things are still pretty small, like Chromes and Firefox's toolbars and certain apps. So, what I would like to know is how can I setup Ubuntu so I can comfortably view things on the setup I have at the distance I am at? Is there a theme that can improve my experience? Or am I forced to sit closer?

On a side note, I have a 5.1 audio setup hooked up to my TV(via composite since it's and older speaker setup) and my pc hooked up via hdmi to the tv. Can I just run the edit mentioned [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SurroundSound) to get 5.1 audio to work, or am I stuck using 2 channel audio(not the biggest deal, but it would be nice to use it as my previous device a roku 2 was able to. Thank you.

Comment: I got the 5.1 issue fixed, but still having issues with everything being too small on my tv at distance?

Comment: Internal to firefox I believe you can also increase the font sizes. Aside from that, you'll probably want to look up ways to manually customize the gtk theme.